# Raw_input for python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm  a beginner on codeacademy and have been trying to recreate this correct answer in spyder. I keep on getting "NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined".

original=raw_input("Enter a word: ")
print original

I've tried a number of variations, but can't seem to troubleshoot this. I'd love any help!